# C# Compare User AD Groups to MVC Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

My goal is to get the current users' AD groups and if they match a dbset model then only display such items.

```
UserPrincipal cuser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pcontext, User.Identity.Name);
var ugroups = cuser.GetAuthorizationGroups().Select(s => s.Name);
var sites = new List<Site>();

if (cuser != null)
{
   if (IsGroupMember(cuser.ToString(), "AD_Group"))
   {
       //This works as intended, the entire list is displayed.
      sites = _context.Sites.ToList();
   }
   else
   {
      //This doesn't work and where i'm trying to make the comparison.
      sites = _context.Sites.Where(w => w.Name = ugroups).ToList();
   }

}
```

Here is the Site Model:

```
public class Site
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SiteAbbreviation { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
sites = _context.Sites.Where(w => ugroups.Contains(w.Name)).ToList();
```

That will give you a list of sites, where the site name matches one of the groups.

Comment: This code makes sense but then I get the following error:
"Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'string'" on the "ugroups.Contains(w.Name)" portion.

Comment: Never Mind. I forgot to remove the "w.Name" shortly after the arrow. Thank You!